# drawing in Android makes UI slow

Tags: android, android-canvas

I follow an example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1045443/Android-Drawing-App-Tutorial-Pt) to create a drawing app. Everything worked great but FPS dropped to 10 after drawing for a while. I did check the time for calling `Path.lineTo()` and `onDraw`. both are pretty fast. I have no idea why this happened and how to find out where caused the slowness. One thing I did notice is that everything works great again after calling `Path.reset()`, so I would assume something happened in `Path` when calling `lineTo()` slows down the UI. Here is the monitor of my device when drawing. [image]

Please help me out! thanks

**Edited**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    //respond to down, move and up events
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            Log.d(TAG, "TIME in move: " +(System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    //redraw
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0 , 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    Log.d(TAG, "TIME in onDraw: " +(System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
}
```

basically everything was taken from the tutorial. it does do its job but I have no clue what slows down UI and why calling `reset()` would make everything normal again.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to your question instead of linking with an offsite url?

Comment: the code in the link looks ok on the first look.

Comment: You are needlessly painting `canvasBitmap` on each touch event, whereas that bitmap hasn't been invalidated/changed in any ways. You only need to redraw `drawPath`. Keep a boolean flag indicating whether the bitmap has been drawn or not and draw it when it hasn't yet been drawn.

Comment: even if I commented out drawBitmap, it still slows down UI after a while

Comment: Aren't there any logs?

Comment: nothing in the log except my timestamps keep printing 0 or 1